# Align text to the right while keeping some text at noindent position

Tags: packages

I would like to align the text to the right somehow. I tried something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Chapter 1:} \quad \lipsum[1]

\bigbreak

\noindent \textbf{Chapter 2:} \quad \lipsum[2-3]

\bigbreak

\noindent \textbf{Chapter 3:} \quad \lipsum[4]

\bigbreak

\end{document}
```

I would like the entire text to be at the position of the first `quad` except for the chapters that I want at their `noindent` position.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: One way is to use `\hangindent`.  Another is to put a `\makebox` and a minipage [t] on the same line (widths sum to `\textwidth`}.  You can also set `\leftskip` and use `\noindent\llap{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{...}}` for the title.

Comment: You might also consider using a tabular or longtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using lists?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show frames

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{Chapter~\arabic*:}},left=0cm]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item[\textbf{Summary:}] \lipsum[3] % <-- supress item label
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sigur. I have another question though that was not listed in the original. I want to add another `item` that is not a chapter. For example, let us called it "summary". I tried to use `enumerate` again with only one `item` titled "summary". However, it is not aligned with the `enumerate` below. How can I make them aligned?

Comment: @naughty_waves, see my edited code.

Comment: You're a lifesaver (or thesis saver), @Sigur. Thank you again!

Comment: @naughty_waves, welcome.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you yet another time, @Sigur. Your answer already answered everything that I asked for and more, but I have another question that is related. If I have an `item` significantly smaller than the other, like "test". It will not be aligned at the right border as it will be closer to the text on the left. Is there a possible to enforce that all `item titles` start at the the point at the right? Thank you again.

Comment: @naughty_waves, add `align=left` to the options. So, use `[label={\textbf{Chapter~\arabic*:}},left=0cm,align=left]`.

Answer (score 0):

The key to most approaches is to measure the width, which can be done using a savebox.  Note that `\hangindent` only affects one paragraph, which is why I did not use it here.

If, on the other hand, you want them all aligned, then you need to choose a width ahead of time.  (Which largely depends on whether you intend to list more than 9 chapters.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myindent}[2]% #1=title, #2=text
{\bgroup% use local box register
  \sbox0{\textbf{#1}\quad}% measure width
  \leftskip=\wd0
  \noindent\llap{\usebox0}#2\par
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\myindent{Chapter 1:}{\lipsum[1]}

\bigbreak

\myindent{Chapter 2:}{\lipsum[2-3]}

\bigbreak

\myindent{Chapter 3:}{\lipsum[4]}

\bigbreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @John Kormylo. One of the things I enjoy of `LaTeX` is that there are many ways to the solution!